# Calculate averages and sums on a monthly database

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, scipy

I have a monthly database and the daily data are every 15 minutes. Develop a script to calculate the average and sum of some variables. The data have the following structure:

> MagViento,       DirViento,          u,       v,      Humedad,
>   Precipitacion
>   5.67,              245 ,      7.7898,     6.5660,         100,          4.1

When I run the script, I get the following output:

```
  Fecha      DirRes     Humedad    MagRes  PreciAcu  Temperatura

2011/07/01  141.058824   100.000000  4.647059      30.4   21.367059              
2011/07/02  153.823529   99.823529  3.470588      18.0    21.841765    
2011/07/03  133.882353   99.823529  4.647059       4.0    21.347059
```

Now I want to save the output to a csv file, but I would like the columns were rounded to 1, eg: `153.82 = 153.8.`
After that i get this, now i want to convert the columns:
DirRes and Humedad to an integer
Magres, PreciAcu and Temperatura remain as float

How can I achieve this in pandas or if there is another way to get this, appreciate your help

Comment: The best way would be to write a program.  It would be faster than retyping it.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you already know how to read your output into a `pandas` `DataFrame`, you can use the `to_csv()` method to output to a csv file, and add `float_format='%.1f'` to the method call to round decimals in your output to one place. You can round the other columns and convert them to integers using `round()` followed by `astype(int)`

This would be accomplished by the following

```
my_data_frame['DirRes'] = my_data_frame['DirRes'].round().astype(int)
my_data_frame['Humedad'] = my_data_frame['Humedad'].round().astype(int)
my_data_frame.to_csv('some_file_name.csv', float_format='%.1f')
```

For more on `pandas.DataFrame.to_csv()`, see the [documention](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html).